# How to add expression to label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been able add a facet based label, however, how do I make it label as the text:

"Mean = 0.235" instead of just "0.235"

Here's my `ggplot`, where the important part is `geom_text`:

```
ggplot(data = filter(season_melt,(HOUSEHOLD_ID_ANONYMISED %in% c(37218002754,37218032412, 38443537620))), aes(factor(HOUSEHOLD_ID_ANONYMISED), value)) + 
geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(HOUSEHOLD_ID_ANONYMISED))) + 
facet_wrap(~Season) + 
theme(text = element_text(size=40), legend.position = "none") + 
xlab("Household ID") + 
ylab("Usage") + 
geom_hline(data = mean_season, aes(yintercept = Mean), size = 1, colour = "blue", linetype = "dashed") + 
geom_text(data = mean_season, aes(0,Mean,label = round(Mean,3),  vjust = -1, hjust = -0.1), color = "blue", size = 11)
```

Here's a pic which shows the labels in each facet:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have (at least) two options.

1. Create the appropriate character string

   ```
   # Something like
   geom_text(data = mean_season, 
          aes(0, Mean, label = sprintf('Mean = %0.3f', Mean),
              vjust = -1, hjust = -0.1),
          color = "blue", size = 11)
   # or
         geom_text(data = mean_season, 
          aes(0, Mean, label = paste('Mean = ',round(Mean, 3)),
              vjust = -1, hjust = -0.1),
          color = "blue", size = 11)
   ```
2. Use `parse=TRUE` in the call to `geom_text`. In this case you would need to construct an appropriate expression according to `?plotmath` (and `?geom_text`)

   ```
     geom_text(data = mean_season, parse = TRUE
          aes(0, Mean, label = paste('Mean ==',round(Mean, 3)),
              vjust = -1, hjust = -0.1),
          color = "blue", size = 11)
   ```

Option 2 will create a *"nicer"* looking expression when visualized.